# an easy way to get all the table rows from a table without using a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to get all the table rows from a table without using a  loop.

I thought that this would work  but it only alerts the first row.

http://jsfiddle.net/THPWy/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var O = $('#mainTable').find('tr');
        //var O = $('#mainTable tr');

        alert(O.html());

       //alerts     <th>Month</th><th>Savings</th> 

    });





<table id ="mainTable" border="1">
  <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>m</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>j</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>july</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aug</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sep</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When you say "get all the table rows" what do you mean? How do you want to use those rows?  In your sample you just display the html?

Comment: The same concept as in css if you go  #mainTable tr{background:red;} then that selects all the rows in that table and applies that style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
// get all tr (excluding the caption)
var O = $('table#mainTable').children().slice(1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/THPWy/7/

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you use will be iterating through each row to get the inner HTML out of it. So no, you cannot do it without a loop.

Here is an alternate method that gets the message in one line if that's what you're after, it's slightly less efficient than going with a loop though as it needs to make a new array.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/THPWy/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows = $('#mainTable tr');
    var message = $.map(rows, function (v) { 
        return v.innerHTML;
    }).join('\n');
    alert(message);
});
```

I would recommend just doing it in a regular loop.

---

FYI `.html()` only alerts the first row because that's what [it was designed to do](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html1) as that is what would be most useful.

> Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your code already retrieves all table rows as an `array` of `jQuery` elements:

```
var trs = $('#mainTable').find('tr');
```

If you want to print the html contents of each row then you would have to use a loop:

```
trs.each(function (index, element) {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: but then why does $('#mainTable tr').html() only alert the first row? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can get by using

```
gt(), lt(),eq()
```

`.gt(index)` // will get all the rows greater than specified index

`.lt(index)` // will get all the rows less than specified index

`.eq(index)` // will get all the rows equal to  specified index

For Example

`$('#mainTable tr').eq(1)` will give second row

But when you want to know all the table rows data then go with Konstantin D - Infragistics solution